# Contributions to TeX related journals are Welcome from TeX community! TUGboat, Ars TeXnica, Die TeXnische Komödie

Tags: discussion, community

Our community is growing and many people are around who are expert in various parts of TeX and friends.

While the site is a very good place where looking for ideas and help when we have a problem to solve, a traditional paper about a topic might be much more helpful.

There are a few journals devoted to TeX, typography and related topics and contributing to them would surely improve the knowledge basis, especially considering that the journals' issues become free reading after a short time. Hence contributions to TeX related journals are Welcome! from fellow TeX Users to share their knowledge and experiences. Below is a few list of notable Journals and their website information for prospective authors:

### TUGboat

http://tug.org/TUGboat (main page)

http://tug.org/TUGboat/location.html (information about submissions and deadlines)

### Ars TeXnica

http://www.guitex.org/home/en/arstexnica (main page)

http://www.guitex.org/home/en/collabora-autori (information about submissions)

### Die TeXnische Komödie

http://www.dante.de/DTK.html (main page, German)

http://www.dante.de/DTK_en.html (main page, English)

<sub>Feel free to add other journals and suggestions</sub>

Comment: What's the question? :)

Comment: @cfr If there's any objection.

Comment: To egreg writing articles for journals?

Comment: @cfr There's no question. This is a kind request to everybody to provide articles on interesting topics. If you have an idea but you're not sure whether the topic is interesting, you can always ping **egreg** or **barbarabeeton** in the chat, they are highly involved with two of the journals.

Comment: @cfr also [Herbert](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478/) if you plan to write for DTK :)

Comment: @yo' I have no ideas :(.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, I've always thought it would be good to crowd-source the writing of the code for a particular journal article.

I got a lot of near real-time help on my 2003 article on fonts (http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-2/tb77adams.pdf) from Giuseppe Bilotta --- I believe that we could get a lot more articles w/ similar collaboration.

So, naïve typographically-oriented person breaks an article down into question-sized chunks, posts the questions here, they get commented on, answered and edited, then the OP concatenates the whole, writes up some framing text and submits it as an article?

Comment: interesting concept.  and isn't it time for you to think about writing another one?

Comment: +1 from me. @barbarabeeton +1 from you as well:-)?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen -- i think i'd like to see a result first.  "crowdsourcing" can be very effective, but it can also have abysmally uneven results.  the editor waives judgment at this instant.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea is laudable and I have a general suggestion to promote it: A good answer on this site not only answers the question, but links to further reading on the general topic in one of the scholarly journals on TeX or typography. Contributors may work their way up to writing an article if they start by recognizing related, published work when providing answers.